# Spark - Register model objects with Kyro - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered:

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am registering the classes which has business logic and model classes with Kyro in spark . I get the below exception

```
> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 14 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times,
> most recent failure: Lost task 14.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 90, **):
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: Object[]
> Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(Object[].class);  at
> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:442)     at
> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:79)
>   at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:472)     at
> com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:565)     at
> org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializerInstance.serialize(KryoSerializer.scala:296)
>   at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:239)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> 
> Driver stacktrace:
```

Kyro Registrtor :

```
public class KyroSerializer implements KryoRegistrator {

        @Override
        public void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
            kryo.register(People.class);
            kryo.register(Lookup.class);

        }
    }
```

Model class:

```
    class people implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; ...... }

    public class Lookup implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String code1;
        private String code2;

}
```

Finally my Spark context :

> sc.set("spark.kryo.registrator", KyroSerializer.class.getName())

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, it seems that kryo has not registered a class object for `Object[]` (array whose entries are of type `Object`). Please try to change your code as follows:

```
public class KyroSerializer implements KryoRegistrator {

    @Override
    public void registerClasses(Kryo kryo) {
        kryo.register(Object[].class);     // add this line to your class
        kryo.register(People.class);
        kryo.register(Lookup.class);
    }
}
```

In addition, I would register your custom registrator class with spark like this

```
sc.set("spark.kryo.registrator", KyroSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
```

If it works for you, though, then just ignore my last remark.